# How to map Perforce with required changelist in View: mapping?

Tags: mapping, perforce

Is there any options in perforce to map the file with specific changelist.
e.g: 
I want to map the file with changelist 12345(latest changelist for the file is 12350)

But I want to map the file having the 12345 changelist.

Is there something like as below?:

//depot/MAIN/test.py/...@12345 //my_workspace/MAIN/test.py/...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ChangeView field to specify that a particular path can never be synced beyond a particular changelist:

```
View:
    //depot/MAIN/test.py //my_workspace/MAIN/test.py

ChangeView:
    //depot/MAIN/test.py@12345
```